# methods and call by reference

Tags: java, methods

I am attempting to use methods to display a value and then display it alternately in different decimal formats. the main issue is that i cannot call up the value after it is entered. that is the only problem I am aware of, but If there are other things i am not grasping, Id be very appreciative of any insight.

```
//*************************************************
//Hwk8 This Program displays Java Methods
//Written By: Daniel Kellogg
//Last Modified: 11/05/12
//************************************************
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;  
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.JOptionPne;

public class Hwk8 {
        public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
                double value; 
                double value2;
                double value3;
                double value4;
                double value5;

                value = getValue();
                System.out.println(value);

                value2 = getValue2();
                System.out.println(value2);

                value3 = getValue3();
                System.out.println(value3);

                value4 = getValue4();
                System.out.println(value4);

                value5 = getValue5();
                System.out.println(value5);

                System.exit(0);
        }


        public static double value()
        {
                double value;
                value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter value");
                return value;
        }

        public static double value2(value) throws IOException
        {
                double value2;
                value2 = roundToInteger(value);
                return value2;
        }       

        public static double value3(value) throws IOException
        {       
            double value3;
            value3 = roundToTenths(value);
            return value3;
        }

        public static double value4(value) throws IOException
        {
                double value4;
                value4 = roundToHundredths(value);
                return value4;
        }

        public static double value5(value) throws IOException
        {       
                double value5;
                value5 = roundToThousandths(value);
                return value5;
        }
}
```

Comment: You mention call by reference in the title, but there's no indication of the relevance to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your method declarations are invalid:

```
public static double value2(value)
```

You need to provide the parameter *type*, e.g.

```
public static double value2(double value)
```

You then need to provide an *argument* for that parameter when you call it, e.g.

```
value2 = getValue2(value);
```

Other notes:

- I'd also strongly advise you to declare your local variables at the point of first use, rather than declaring them all right at the start of the method.
- You don't need to call `System.exit(0)` - your process will already exit when the `main` method finishes (as you haven't created any threads)
- Your methods would never throw `IOException` - why are you declaring that they might?
- Your methods each declare a local variable, then assign a value, then return the value. Why not do it in one step?

  ```
  return roundToTenths(value); // Complete body of value3
  ```

  (At that point, the method itself is pointless, of course, as you can just call `roundToTenths` instead...)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling functions with names like `getValue`, but the functions you've quoted have names like `value`. Perhaps a half-complete renaming?

In your `main`, you won't have access to your `value` *function* via just the identifier `value`, because you've defined a local variable with that name which shadows it. So to use the `value` *function*, you need to use its fully-qualified name, `Hkw8.value`.